# Jquery toggle and reset form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to show and hide some form elements according to a checkbox selection.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        <input name="address_check" value="1" type="checkbox">
        <span class="lbl"> Yes, My postal address is different</span>
    </label>
</div>

<div id="address2"> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="street_no">Street No:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" name="street_no" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="street_name">Street Name:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
             <input type="text" name="street_name" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I want to display `#address2` DIV if `address_check` check box checked and other wise it should be hide.

This how I tried it.

```
$('input[name="address_check"]').bind('change',function(){
  $('#address2').fadeToggle(!$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

My problem is I want to reset the form elements inside `address2` div when this is toggling down. Reset mean I want to make empty these elements.

Can anybody tell me how to do it? 
Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to toggle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing:

```
$('#address2').find("input").val("");

$("#address2").find('select option:first').prop('selected',true);
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9vvacfq/1/)

Comment: Yes its working. But if I have a select box inside that target DIV. what can I do. I tried it something like this - `.find("select").prop('selectedIndex',0);` but it doesn't work for me

Comment: void, I cannot get it to work. My `select` is not resetting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var address2 = $('#address2');
$('input[name="address_check"]').bind('change',function(){
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

    isChecked ? address2.fadeIn() : address2.fadeOut();

    if(!isChecked)
    {
        address2.find('input, textarea').val('');
        address2.find('select').prop('selectedIndex',0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is using:

```
    $("#address2 :input").val("");
    $("#address2 :select").prop('selected',false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(function(){
 $('input[name="address_check"]').bind('change',function(){
    $('#address2').fadeToggle(!$(this).is(':checked'));
    $("#address2 :input").val("");
    $("#address2 :select").prop('selected',false);
  });
});

</script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        <input name="address_check" value="1" type="checkbox">
        <span class="lbl"> Yes, My postal address is different</span>
    </label>
</div>

<div id="address2"> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="street_no">Street No:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" name="street_no" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="street_name">Street Name:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
             <input type="text" name="street_name" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" />
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="street_name">select Name:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
             <select name="name" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" >
             <option value="1">1</option>
             <option value="2">2</option>
              </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you how to reset dropdown list?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('input[name="address_check"]').bind('change',function(){
  $('#address2').fadeToggle(!$(this).is(':checked'));

      $('#address2').find("input").val("");

});
```